# How to set the path to compile my CSS with Compass SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have been looking around and it seems an issue quite diffused, but i am not finding the solution for my case.

I have set up my first Compass Project following [these instructions](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass)

My folder project is called sass-test

I have my css files

- screen.css
- print.css
- ie.css
- config.rb

My config.rb inside is set up in this way

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheet"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Then I have my sass folder with:

- screen.scss
- print.scss
- ie.scss

I do some changes in my screen.scss file and then i compile it by the terminal giving this command

```
compass compile sass-test/sass/screen.scss
```

Now it happens that the automatically COMPASS generates new folders

- stylesheet
- test
- sass
  .In this folder Compass compiles `screen.css`

I dont want my screen.css compiled there but i want it inside my sass-test where there is already existing the screen.css file.

How can i achieve that? I also look up in this [article](http://css-tricks.com/compass-compiling-and-wordpress-themes/) reading all the comments but i can not figure it out the issue.

I have also tried to compile it by *liveReload preprocessor* setting up the Outputfolder but it's still compiling the screen.css in the "wrong" path.

how can i give the instructions to Compass to compile my screen.css file in my sass-test?

Here the print screen[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have sorted it out the issue, i start from the beginning calling the project differently ( without any hyphen) then i set up the output folder by LiveReload preprocessor and anytime i edit any scss file, it compiles straight to the relative css file inside the stylesheet folder. In this way i do not use any command line

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `css_dir = "stylesheet"` in your config.rb to point to where you want the compiled CSS files to go.  In your case, it sounds like you want it here:

```
css_dir = "./"
```

You'll probably need to enable relative URLs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have tried to edit as you said css_dir="./" but it's still compilling in the other path. I have followed all the istructions, this is exactly my case https://github.com/thesassway/sass-test/blob/master/config.rb. How can i enable relative URLs?

Comment: Uncomment line #15:  `# relative_assets = true`

Comment: i did it too already couse i look up here http://backtothefront.net/2011/compass-sass-quick-start-guide/, but it's not compiling rightly. This is my config.rb right now : http_path = "/"
css_dir = "./"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
output_style = :expanded
relative_assets = true

Comment: Maybe i need to config the project_path?

Comment: Hm, I have a project where the Sass files are outside of webroot and it is able to compile them to "../static/css" ("./" works as well), but my config.rb is always located one step above my sass directory (eg. `compass compile sass/file.scss`).  Is it still placing the CSS files into the "css" directory?

Comment: Once i give the command line, Compass creates automatically 3 folders outside the Webroot, the three folders are - stylesheets - test and - sass. Inside the sass folder it place the css file. That's very weird

Comment: I have uploaded a print-screen in the question, now it's cleared what it does

Comment: Try running your command from within the sass-test directory where your config.rb lives.  Wonder if the hyphen in the directory name is confusing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23015/discussion-between-cimmanon-and-manna)

Comment: i have a very bad connection now to chat :(, i am trying to create a new Compass project avoiding the hyphen in the directory, just to make sure it's not caused by it.

Comment: Is your Compass up to date?  This is what it looks like when I attempt both a watch and a compile outside of the project directory:  https://gist.github.com/ae2bc8ea46fc81853911.  It won't let me compile files individually unless I'm within the project directory.

Comment: ok i got it, this is my Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam), i should upgrade?

Comment: That's the current version.  You don't have any stray config.rb files hanging around outside of the `sass-test` directory do you?

Comment: No, there is not, it can not make conflict, cimmanom, i give you my details in pvt, i do not want to make this thread too long. i keep you posted on my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because all paths defined in the project configuration file are relative to the current shell path, you must run the command `compass` from the root of your project, that is to say, since the directory `sass-test`:

```
cd sass-test
compass compile sass/screen.scss
```

Or just the command `compass compile` to compile all files.

Answer (score 0):

This may also help, if you wish to have different defaults for what folders compass uses, everytime (one off just edit your config.rb)

edit/add the following to your ~/.bash_profile

```
alias compass_init="compass init --syntax=sass --css-dir=css --javascripts-dir=js"
```